# Keeping a AngularJS bootstrap popover visible as element updates

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angularjs-bootstrap

I'm using an AngularJS [bootstrap popover](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover) on an element using `popover-trigger='mouseenter'`. The element updates using [angularFire](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire), and after an update, the popover disappears until I move my mouse (even within the element).

How can I get the popover to remain visible after an update?

Answer (score 1):

When the model updates the directive might be getting reinitiated. Therefore, as the mouse is already over the element and stationary the `mouseenter` event is not fired.

Most likely you will have to edit the `popover` directive and add a function to the `link function` which checks the position of the mouse and if the mouse is over the trigger then it will keep the popover visible. However, this might cause flickering.

Or you can silently update the model so that the directive doesn't get reinitiated. If you post some sample code or a jsfiffle/plunker I would be able explain how to do that.